# Combine List and ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0

I have a WPF application that contains a datagrid which is bound to a List. My List implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. So I can see when a property has changed. However when a new item is added or deleted there is no event to tell me this has happened.

After reading I have seen an ObservableCollection can tell me when an item has been added or deleted via the CollectionChanged event. However the ObservableCollection has a few short comings that a list overcomes.

So my question is if it's possible to combine a List & ObservableCollection so you have the functionality of both? Is it possible to have List inherit from? If so are there any methods that need to be overwritten?

Comment: What feature(s) of List do you want that ObservableCollection doesn't already offer?

Comment: @p.s.w.g The only thing I can think of is that `ObservableCollection` doesn't have `AddRange`. But that is easily solved with extensions

Comment: Have you seen [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx)?

Comment: @Jim Well, there are actually a number of methods that are defined only on List<T> (compare [List<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) and [ObservableCollection<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) on MSDN), such as `BinarySearch`, `ForEach`,  `LastIndexOf`, etc., but `AddRange` is indeed the only one that I would say is frequently used. Most of the `List<T>`-specific ones are covered nicely by Linq anyway. Actually `List<T>` has always seemed a bit bloated to me.

Comment: In particular the add and removal of items seems a lot easier using Lists. Also I could be wrong I thought that ObservableCollection cannot detect if a property has changed in a collection. So in List if a Boolean property was changed from true to false there was no way of being notified - unlike a list?

Comment: I didnt know Tom Sawyer has a brother named Mark :) Just a joke. How about you use BindableList? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to your question is 'yes, but with some work'.

The `ObservableCollection<T>` class extends the `Collection<T>` class, which implements the `IList<T>`, `ICollection<T>`, `IEnumerable<T>`, `IList`, `ICollection`, `IEnumerable` interfaces - the same as the `List<T>` class. However, the `ObservableCollection<T>` class also implements the `INotifyCollectionChanged` and `INotifyPropertyChanged` interfaces, so these are the main difference between the two.

Therefore you could extend the `List<T>` class and manually implement the `INotifyCollectionChanged` and `INotifyPropertyChanged` interfaces yourself to get the best of both worlds. Having said that, after manually adding `AddRange` and `Sort` methods to my custom `ObservableCollection<T>` base class, I have never felt the need to use a `List<T>` to display objects in any of my WPF projects.